# Deaktivate products for Storeview

Tags: multistore, products

we are using Magento v. 1.9.2.1 and set up two languages. Our customer wants to deactivate a few products for a specific language. Even deactivating a category would be fine. But as always, its not that easy. If we deactivate the product for one language, its deactivated for the other as well. Same with the category. 
Is there a way to go around this problem, or an extension.

Thanks for any hint or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the product's visibility attribute per store view.

to do that, in the product's configurations top left corner choose the desired store view. There You can override the visibility setting

Update from Comments:

the better way would be to divide the shop at least on store group level instead of store view level. Then you can have complete different category trees

Comment: Thank you very mutch. Not the best way, but better then nothing. The amount of the products in the category are still visible, but not showing. Fine with that. Thank you very mutch David Verholen

Comment: no problem, yes the better way would be to divide it at least on store group level instead of store views. there you can have complete different category trees. But that's also a lot more work ;)